# Is the measure finitely additive? countably additive?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

The answer is  It is finitely additive but not countably additive.  How can this be proved

Comment: It's really just a matter of looking at the definitions.  Perhaps you could add context to your question by including the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Take as a counterexample the sets $\{1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5,6\},\{7,8,9,10\}...$ and so 
on.

Their union if the whole space,and thus has infinite measure, but the sum of the measures of these sets is $1$

Comment: It may be simpler to just take the singleton sets.

Comment: @MichaelBurr .the answer i posted was the first thing that came up in my mind..But indeed your idea is simpler and better..:)  thank you for the suggestion.